# Some laptop keyboard keys not responding after keyboard being unplugged

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure

EDIT 2: there is no answer for this problem here, it resolved spontaneously a few days after it started. Sorry, future-people.

In opening up my laptop (a Toshiba Satellite C650D) recently, the keyboard (nsk-tnosv 01) ribbon cable came unplugged from the connector. Plugged it back in, no problem, but now some keys won't respond, and consistently the same keys: `, a,b,n, \, numpad-7, numpad-*, left-shift, enter and numpad enter, and the lights for the caps and num locks but those are working correctly.

The keys do not respond anywhere: neither the linux (ubuntu) or windows partitions, nor in grub (the boot-loader, i can test there with its cli).

I initially thought the cable wasn't seated properly, but i have detached and reattached it many times, & it is always these same keys, which might be odd? I don't know. It might still be this even, somehow?

I've searched for possible solutions (here & elsewhere) which haven't been useful per se, but help to rule things out.

I've cleaned the keyboard (easier with it separate) with some jostling, key presses, and vacuum. I've also wiped the cable connector with a new glasses cloth (not a wet one of course just a clean soft cloth). If I had compressed air I'd've used it.

I've done the power reset deal of turning it off, removing the battery, and holding the power button.

I've not done the solutions about software or drivers, as there weren't any software changes surrounding this, and it's malfuctioning across OSes and even in grub.

I'm semi-anxious of mechanical damage, except for the lack of any grouping of the keys. Unless it's wired very weirdly?

I've also not spilled any liquids on it, so I've skipped most of those questions I found where that was what instigated the problem, since that's not the problem source for me.

I've also left my computer on for a while, and have while typing (using an onboard keyboard and some copy-paste) which feels useful, even just in the hopes that the keys would get the idea.

I may have a mechanical fault, but like i said, the lack of grouping makes that seem odd, and while a replacement isnt particularly expensive, that's still money i could use otherwise, so i'd love to know it'd solve it. Meanwhile, I am dealing with an on-screen keyboard but it's non-ideal and not meant for back and forth from mouse to keys, and trying to avoid any typing at all

Thank you very much, and let me know any other diagnostics you'd like.

EDIT: I'll also add that this isn't a new laptop or keyboard

EDIT 2: it just resolved? i was just typing a url with the onboard keyboard, used left-shift out of habit to highlight some characters to replace, and it just worked. All the rest of my keys are working as well, though the lights on the lock keys are still out but w/e. num lock is always on and caps off anyway, and they'll probably resolve now. For the record, this is a few days after the start of my troubles, and like 15 minutes after posting this question. I'm happy of course, but wow is that weird.

EDIT 3: After reboot, the problem returned.

Comment: Sounds like a fault in the keyboards PCB.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because OP stated it spontaneously resolved: *"EDIT 2: there is no answer for this problem here, it resolved spontaneously a few days after it started. Sorry, future-people."*

Comment: it did not stay resolved, unfortunately.

Comment: The symptoms point to (but not guaranteed to be) a problem with the keyboard.  It could be various specific issues, but any of those would be solved by replacing the keyboard.  It sounds like you would be able to do that yourself, so it would probably be the least expensive next step, and would have a good chance of solving the problem.